# enable soft ap on beaglebone green wireless when it is booted from SD card

Tags: beagleboard

when i ssh in to Beagle-bone green wireless and give ifconfig a list of interfaces appeared including softap ,lo usb0 ,wlan .
with the help of 'connmanctl' i was able to scan wifi , connected to one of the service,then i connected mobile phone to the beaglebone AP, a login page was opened immediately once it got connected.
i followed this links :[link1](http://www.cnx-software.com/2016/05/21/getting-started-with-beaglebone-green-wireless-development-board/)

But when i tried to do the same thing when booting the board from SD card with Debian image 8.6 , ifconfig didnt even list softAP.
i was able to make either of ap mode or client mode not both at the same time(using connmanctl).How to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

I also have the BeagleBone Green Wireless and I'm attempting to get my network setup properly. Here's what I know so far.

I'm booting onto the SD card with Debian Stretch IoT from [here...](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images)

When the BBG comes online it's AP broadcast is passworded as BeagleBone.  You can connect to it directly then `ssh debian@192.168.8.1` password: temppwd

Once ssh'd in, you can have it connect to your WiFi by using connmantcl.

```
connmanctl
connmanctl> scan wifi
connmanctl> services
connmanctl> agent on
connmanctl> connect wifi_*_managed_psk
connmanctl> quit
```

More information about the AP can be found [here...](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/software_access_point)

This setup allowed be to have a connection to my network WiFi and an AP on the BBG.  Now I'm trying to find where I can change the AP password...